# How to get the contents of body(json) that has passed in the POST request either from request or response object using Restassured library?

Tags: post, request, rest-assured

I'm trying to read the content passed in the body of the POST request either using RequestSpecification or Response objects of Rest assured library. I could not find any method which can return the passed body content. Any help?

```
public RequestSpecification Request(RequestSpecification rs)
{
    rs = RestAssured.given();
    if(APIConstants.BASEURL.contains("https")) {
        rs = rs.relaxedHTTPSValidation();
        rs.port(443);
    }       
    return rs;
}
public RequestSpecification postRequestBuilder(RequestSpecification rs,String Body)
{
    rs=Request(rs);
    rs = rs.contentType(APIConstants.contentType);
    if(Body!=null) {        
        rs = rs.body(Body); 
    }
    return rs;
}

public Response performPOSTOperation(RequestSpecification rs,String Resource, String TestParameters)
{
    Response rp=null;
    String url=BASEURL+"/"+Resource+"/"+TestParameters;
    System.Out.Println("Request is " +url);
    rp = rs.when().post(url);
           // I am trying to print Request body parameter here.
    System.Out.Println("Response is " +rp.asString());      
    return rp;
}
public void test(){                                                    
            String JSONBody="{"TestNumber":1}";
            RequestSpecification rs;
    rs= postRequestBuilder(rs,JSONBody);
    Response rp= performPOSTOperation(rs,RESOURCE,Service);
}
```

I am trying to print JSONBody passed in test() in PerformPOSTOperation()

Answer (score 0):

You can add .log in your request specification object :

```
rs.log(LogDetail.BODY);
```

or add a filter - details @ https://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.6/io/restassured/filter/log/RequestLoggingFilter.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I tried rs.log(LogDetail.BODY); , I am encountered with the error -" - The method log() in the type RequestSpecification is not applicable for the arguments ". Is there any other way?